# How to solve this N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.?

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I use Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot.

`sudo apt-get update`

I get this:

````
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]      
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yann
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.``` 

How can I solve this?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `cdrom` entry from `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Regarding the PPA, it doesn't have files for Ubuntu 20.04. Remove it too.

Comment: I'm stuck at "Refreshing software cache". Should I wait?

Comment: It is unclear where do you get this message.

Comment: Sofwares & Updates

Comment: it you find solution? Even i'm getting stuck at 'Refreshing software cache'